# Excel VBA - Access Website, generate report & press save on IE dialog bar

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, save-as

I have a question regarding a topic that is already discussed in some other threads and forums but I do not manage to make it work for me. So I came here to ask that questions concerning my individual code.

Basically, I access an intranet-site and based on some input (via checkboxes) a report is created with data from SAP.

My problem arises after the report is generated and IE prompts me to press the "save" button on its dialog box. I do not manage to automate that part.

Could you help me here? I would like to store the report in the "Downloads" Folder.

You'll find my code below.
Due to compliance reasons I cannot show the original URL.

Any help is widely appreciated.

Best
Simon

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim i As Integer

Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://blablablablablabla"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

Set html = ie.document

html.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_RadCboRepFilter1_Arrow").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

html.getElementsByClassName("rcbList")(0).Children(5).Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

html.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_RadCboRepFilter2_Arrow").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

html.getElementsByClassName("rcbList")(0).Children(0).Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

html.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_RadCboListOppStatus_ctl01").Click

html.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_RadCboListOppStatus_ctl02").Click

html.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_RadcboListSalesStage_ctl00").Click

html.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_RadcboListSalesStage_ctl01").Click

html.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_RadcboListSalesStage_ctl02").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

html.getElementById("MainContent_BtnRunReport").Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Base on my experience, when we click the download button, it will show the download prompt in IE browser and let us click the Save button to download the file. Are you sure the IE browser lets you click the Save As button, instead of the Save button. Please check your website code, make sure you set the download file name. If you could post the related code about how to generate the report and download file, it might be easier for us to help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, When download file from IE browser, it will display a prompt to let user click the Save button. 
we could use the Application.SendKeys "%{s}" command to click the Save button in VBA.

Sample code as below:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "<the website url>"

        While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        'click the button to download the file.
        IE.Document.getElementbyId("btnDowloadReport").Click

        'wait the download prompt appear
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

        Application.SendKeys "%{s}"

        'Waiting for the site to load.
    End With
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Html page resource:

```
<a id="btnDowloadReport" href="https://research.google.com/pubs/archive/44678.pdf" download>Download</a>
```

[Note] Please check your IE browser setting, make sure the Download path is the  "Downloads" Folder.